Nginx issue- Simple load balancing results in nginx default page
I created a FASTAPI service that I containerized and made 3 service replicas of it. Then I added nginx loadbalancer service in docker as well and created nginx.conf with upstream.
When I open the defined address, i do not get the correct page but instead get nginx default page.

Folder Structure
└── ngnx-fastapi-docker
    └── README.md
    └── docker-compose.yaml
    └── nginx
        └── nginx.conf
    └── project
        └── .dockerignore
        └── Dockerfile
        └── Pipfile
        └── Pipfile.lock
        └── main.py

nginx.conf
http {
  upstream projectapp {
    server app1:8000;
    server app2:8000;
    server app3:8000;
  }

server { 
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://projectapp;
    }
  }
}

docker-compose.yaml
version: "3" 
services: 
  app1:
    build: project
    container_name: project_app
    command: pipenv run uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --reload
    ports:
      - 8010:8000
    volumes:
      - ./project:/app 

      
  app2: 
    build: project 
    container_name: project_app2 
    command: pipenv run uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --reload
    ports:
      - 8011:8000

    volumes:
      - ./project:/app

  app3: 
    build: project
    container_name: project_app3
    command: pipenv run uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --reload
    ports:
      - 8012:8000

    volumes:
      - ./project:/app

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: project_LB
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf;


Dockerfile
FROM python:3.12.0-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /app/

RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip && pip install pipenv

RUN pipenv install

RUN pipenv run pip list

COPY . /app


I'm on a MAC using vscode Version: 1.89.0
I tried adding network in the compose.yaml but it still resulted in the same default page.
I am new to docker and nginx. Please help me.
